# How to implement slider in modal box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I am trying to implement slider inside the modal box but this is not working. 
I am using modal box and trying to implement slider inside the modal box.

Here is my code:

```
$("#lightSlider").lightSlider({ 
    auto:false,     
    adaptiveHeight: false,      
});
```

Slider is coming only then I do inspect from browser and modal box keeps changing its size during inspect element.

Any idea why this is happening or do I need to change my slider?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a carousal slider inside your modal body

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
</ol><div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="item active">
  <img src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania">
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania">
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower">
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower">
</div>
```

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
```

```
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```